# Symfony6 EasyAdmin4 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I recently put my project into production. And since then I can no longer create, edit and delete. I am automatically redirected to my dashboard and in my console log I have a 406 error (Not Acceptable)

Especially since I had no problem when I was local.
Thank you in advance for your help

I am using EasyAdmin version 4.4 and Symfony 6.0

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;


use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Skills;
use App\Entity\Project;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route; 
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\AdminUrlGenerator;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Provider\AdminContextProvider;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{

    private $adminContextProvider;

    public function __construct(AdminContextProvider $adminContextProvider)
    {
        $this->adminContextProvider = $adminContextProvider;
    }

    #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/dashboard.html.twig');
    }


    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('My Project');
    }


    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linktoRoute('Back to the website', 'fa-solid fa-rotate-left', 'app_home');
        yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', 'fa fa-home');
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Profil', 'fas fa-user', User::class);
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Projects', 'fas fa-list', Project::class);
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Skills', 'fa-solid fa-gears', Skills::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I assume you have a .env value somewhere that indicates whether you're using a dev or prod environment. What happens if you toggle that value to `prod` on your local machine? Does the same problem then occur locally? That will help you determine whether this is related to your production infrastructure in some way -- a difference in nginx configuration on a server or something similar, for example -- or if it's a problem in your project's PHP source code

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer.
if I put prod local yes it still works

Comment: Ok, then that means you have some infrastructure that's different. I'd say your best bet is to dump system information on both systems with `phpinfo()` -- being sure to put it behind a basic auth wall so you don't leak information insecurely to the public -- and compare what comes out. The biggest differences I can think of would be the types of server software you're using -- apache vs nginx or something else, or maybe just different major version numbers -- and the version of PHP you're using. But there are lots of other settings that could also be responsible for the change

Comment: Thank you very much I found a solution, I had to generate an SSL and it works.
thanks again